# Get approximate age of git commit

Tags: git

I am making a script that shows changes in code behaviour since last run of CI.

I am trying to place something like this in the UI and logs:

`6488e55b - (17 hours ago)`

How can I do that? Some variant of `git log`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `--relative-date`

From `git log --help`

```
--relative-date
       Synonym for --date=relative.
--date=relative shows dates relative to the current time, e.g. “2 hours ago”. The -local option has no effect for --date=relative.
```

To get the exact format you gave, you can use a format string

```
# %h is abbreviated hash
# %cr is the relative date
git log --format='%h - (%cr)'
c114695 - (20 hours ago)
5b436fb - (24 hours ago)
81f133b - (24 hours ago)
212901a - (24 hours ago)
73247c7 - (24 hours ago)
fb21d9c - (2 days ago)
61a6e2e - (2 days ago)
9d15d6b - (2 days ago)
6c13608 - (7 days ago)
```